# Is "slung it off far into the distance" idiomatic?

Tags: idiomatic-language

"Far into the distance" seem to mean "far away". "Slung it off" seems to mean "throw it", so the phrase makes sense, but does it? I rarely heard it being used this way. I am not sure, but "off" might be ungrammatical here, is it? How would you reword it? Are there better alternatives to "far into the distance"?

For example:

> Hercules slung a spear off far into the distance, with his inhumane
>   strength.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is where the subject may be "subjective." This seems to be about Hercules, the mythical Greek hero. Therefore, there is a poetic element here that informs the word choice. It wouldn't be *wrong* to use "slung a spear off far into the distance" elsewhere, but it would seem more awkward in a more mundane context. In particular, the word "slung" is not a typical one.

The word "off" in "off far" seems to insist to me that this is being thrown a great distance, but those two words won't be used in isolation. It could be

> Hercules slung a spear off far towards a target

or even

> Hercules fired an arrow off far into the distance

"Far off" is much more common:

> On a clear day, you can make out Haleakala far off in the distance.

You could, therefore, switch "far" and "off:"

> Hercules slung a spear far off into the distance...

But I will emphasize that in this poetic context at least, the grammar is flexible and not necessarily wrong; I prefer this last sentence to the original one, but, the original one has a different emphasis, it's "quicker" and less expected; the event occurs in the sentence almost before you've read the words that made it happen. Perhaps it emphasizes Hercules' strength; I don't know.